Firebase Cloud Messaging: Are messages dropped/throttled inconsistently?
I'm sending FCM messages via a scheduled cloud function repeated every 10 minutes only for testing purposes and a lot of notifications don't end up on the device. Is this because there's a throttling mechanism at play? Any way of figuring out why/where my notifications are getting dropped? Generating and using a new token seems to fix the problem temporarily.
. Here's the code:
exports.kickOffUTCRemindersDue = onSchedule("*/10 * * * * ", async (event) => {
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title: "Hello World",
      body: "This is me calling",
    },
    token: "TOKEN"
  };
  getMessaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });


  // response.json({ message: 'Hello from Firebase!' });
});

The logs are all error-free. So is the send dashboard:

